# I want to make a picturebox disappear after a certain time has passed without using a control

Tags: c#, timer, picturebox

Hello I am kind of new to C#... I have a picturebox which is my control. It's meant to be rapidly clicked on. I want to make it so when it is clicked a certain amount of times a second picturebox which has a .gif in it becomes visible. And when a certain amount of time has past without clicking the first picturebox the second disappears. Is there a way to do this? Maybe with timers. Some sample code will help me out A LOT! Thanks to all in advance! :)

Comment: Pretty important to try to figure this out for yourself, it just takes standard code with most of it generated by the designer.  That's the way you stop being "kind of new".  Post what you've tried so far so we can see what hang-up you are suffering from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer1.Interval=60000;//one minute
timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
timer1.Start();

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    timer1.Stop();
    timer1.Start();
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do whatever you want            
    pictureBox2.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I've been trying all day dude! I couldn't get it to work :( Thanks a bunch I will take notes from this code and learn it :) THANKS!!!