# make picturebox randomly appear every 5 minutes then disappear after it crosses the game screen if the player doesn't kill it

Tags: c#

Working on a game similar to R type and I got the minor minions to appear so the player can kill them. My idea is to have a boss appear randomly appear every 5 minutes then disappear after it crosses the game screen if the player doesn't kill it. Including what was suggested here
[I want to make a picturebox disappear after a certain time has passed without using a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425257/i-want-to-make-a-picturebox-disappear-after-a-certain-time-has-passed-without-us)

I've tried timer1.start() then timer1.stop(). But it stops the whole game and I just want it to control the boss not the entire game. If someone has an easier or better idea please show me.

```
        private void Game_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 600;//one minute
            timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void powerarmour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            timer1.Start();
        }
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Arrow_key_movement();
            Explosion();
            movebullet();
            //Enemies_move();
            Health();
            //HitorMiss();
            RandomEnemies();
            //
            Random mpa = new Random();
            int pa;
            powerarmour.Visible = false;
            if (powerarmour.Left > 0)
            {
                powerarmour.Visible = true;
                pa = mpa.Next(50, 500);
                healthup.Location = new Point(1200, pa);
            }
        }
```

One idea that sort of worked make the boss appear for a second then disappear. Which was this

```
void RandomEnemies()
        {
            p++;
            Random mpa = new Random();
            int pa;

            powerarmour.Visible = false;
            if(p == 50 && powerarmour.Left > 0)
            {
                
                
                pa = mpa.Next(50, 500);
                healthup.Location = new Point(1200, pa);
                powerarmour.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can use several timers or you can check for a certain time in a tighter tick.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

For handling just the timer during the game loop as easily as possible, you can add a second timer for the boss and then check the timer in your game loop.

e.g.

```
// Good idea to have a section of configurable variables at the top of your code 
private int _bossTimerIntervalMins => 5;

private void Game_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var bossTimer = new Timer();
    bossTimer.Start();
    bossTimer.Interval = _bossTimerIntervalMins * 60 * 1000;
    bossTimer.Elapsed += BossTimerEvent;

    ... rest of your code ...
}

private void BossTimerEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff with the boss every 5 mins
}
```

**Original Answer**

Part of the problem is you are setting `powerArmour.Visible = false;` on every tick event. So after you've set `powerArmour.Visible = true;` in your validation, it immediately gets reset to false on the next tick.

I would suggest removing the `powerArmour.Visible = false;` line and set it upon initialisation of the game loop instead and add a second check for when you want it to be removed if it's currently visible.

e.g.

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Arrow_key_movement();
            Explosion();
            movebullet();
            //Enemies_move();
            Health();
            //HitorMiss();
            RandomEnemies();
            
            Random mpa = new Random();
            int pa;

            //powerArmour.Visible = false; // removed
            
            if (powerarmour.Left > 0)
            {
                powerArmour.Visible = true;
                pa = mpa.Next(50, 500);
                healthup.Location = new Point(1200, pa);
            }
            
            if(powerArmour.Visible && someOtherCriteria)
            {
                // Logic for removing the item 
                powerArmour.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Likewise, your game crashes because when you reach the `powerarmour_Click` event because the entire game loop is stopped and restarted.

```
    private void powerarmour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

The easiest way to manage specific timed events is to add another timer for the boss and use that instead of `timer1` if it's just a one-off. If you plan on having hundreds, or more, of such timers then a better solution would be to keep the one timer and check it for how many minutes/seconds/whatever have elapsed since it started and calculate if your event needs to fire.

Comment: I have another question for you which I feel I didn't explain in my original question. I didn't want the first boss to appear right away but rather after 5 min of game play. He's suppose to stay invisible till that point.

Comment: You might want to move that `Random mpa = new Random();` out of `timer1_Tick` in case it gets called without a delay.

Comment: @TheOnion13 OK, I've updated my answer with an example of using a second timer just for the boss sequence. If you end up getting more and more cases of needing a timer in the same game loop, then you might also want to look into using `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` instead.

Comment: I kept getting errors under the timer in var bossTimer = new Timer(); so I had to change it to var bossTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(); to make it work. I have a few new questions. I can delay the boss showing on the screen, but how do I make the timer start over for another 5 min? The way I have it now, the boss shows up after 5 min and then continues to appear on the screen.

Comment: private void Game_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var bossTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            powerarmour.Visible = false;
            bossTimer.Start();
            bossTimer.Interval = _bossTimerIntervalMins * 60 * 1000;
            bossTimer.Elapsed += bossTimer_Tick;
            bossTimer.Stop();
            bossTimer.Start();
        }

Comment: private void bossTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random mpa = new Random();
            int pa;
            powerarmour.Left -= 10;
            if (powerarmour.Left < 0)
            {
                powerarmour.Visible = true;
                pa = mpa.Next(50, 500);
                powerarmour.Location = new Point(1200, pa);
            }
        }

Comment: Dour High Arch  What did you mean by move the Random?